# Calling pthread_mutex_init atomically

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, operating-system, posix

If shared access to the code inside some library, among multiple threads is protected by global mutex and when the mutex is being acquired first time we need to call pthread_mutex_init but if multiple thread tries to call library function same time then we need to make sure pthread_mutex_init gets called by only one thread and once.

How can we achieve this ? Library constructors/destructor is one solution but library must support all compilers/platforms. We can use counter and use atomic inc/dec but atomic ++/-- operations on every lock/unlock are expensive. I am looking for any other way. All comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two good choices:

1. Statically initialize the mutex using `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.
2. Use `pthread_once` and a statically initalized `pthread_once_t` to ensure the mutex is initialized once.

Comment: Thanks. I Will try those options.

Comment: pthread_once may use atomic comparison plus one more lock/unlock. Static initialization is better option.

Comment: @Pointer Definitely. It's pretty silly to create and use a statically initialized structure for the sole purpose of avoiding having to statically initialize another comparable structure.